# Loading a property list with a universal file path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, property-list

I was reading about Plist just before and I saw this Bit of code:

```
       [super viewDidLoad];
       NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"projects" ofType:@"plist"];
       projects = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
       }
```

Now I've been manually putting in the file path of my property list, I'm curious is this the correct way to universally find the file path?

if so could someone please explain how it works to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, for getting the file from your Main resources bundle.**

For getting the resource path from you application document directory you can try like

```
/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

which could be use like

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.ext"];
```

Comment: Yes your code is fine for loading the File from NSBundle and from getting the data from Your Application document folder you need the code I provided.

Comment: Just do quick Google on NSBundle and Application document Folder so that you can get better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the right way and its self explanatory too..first step you find the path of plist file and by then you are populating an array with the contents of plist file. If you use mutable array instead of array you can also edit the plist file and save back